# BLE module as beacon for longer range?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, beacon

I am on a search for BLE module that works also as an iBeacon and has an outdoor range of atleast 30 meters on iBeacon mode. I tried HM-10 but it only worked within 10 meters. Can you guys suggest any? Price should be max $10.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Before you abandon the HM-10, consider that its data sheet says it has an output power level of 0 dBm which is typical of Bluetooth LE devices.  The max power level is regulated by government agencies such as the FCC in the United States.  You may not find anything better.

One important point to check: The HM-10's power output is configurable between 3 settings.  Make sure you aren't using a low power setting.

Use `AT+POWE?` to get the current power level, which will return 0, 1, or 2.  If you do not see 2 you are not at the max power.  You can use `AT+POWE2` to set it to the max power level.

Also consider what antenna you are using if any.  Attaching different antennas to bluetooth modules can affect the amount of power that is directed in specific directions.  You might consider using a directional antenna to send the power in the direction of interest.

Depending on where you got your HM-10, it may have  a different development antenna.  TI's development board, for example, has one built in.  Do you know if you have one at all?